# Javascript jquery position of browser display area

Tags: javascript, browser, viewport

I need to position an object at the top of the browser viewport, regardless of the scroll position. Objects have offsetTop. What is the function or object name for the viewport?

Comment: For the browser's sake usually it's `window` but with the DOM it's more likely the `body` or `html` element. In any case, you are better off positioning the element with CSS instead of trying something with JavaScript, unless you are in a browser that does not support the `fixed` position value.

Comment: As long as he isn't using IE6, he should be fine. http://caniuse.com/css-fixed

Comment: BODY was what I was looking for. I'm modifying popupmenu that is available from dynamicdrive.com which cannot use the fixed CSS. It has floating menu's but has a problem when the menu overflows the bottom edge. It places the menu at the top of the document. Using document.body.scrollTop seems to work in all browsers. Many thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

There's the css property:

```
position: fixed;
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: do you mean `position:fixed`?

Comment: Sigh, that's what I get for trying to do two things at once.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use css instead of JavaScript. Add a fixed class to the element or use the css on the element.

```
.fixed { position: fixed; }
```

or

```
.myElement { position: fixed; }
```

You could also dynamically add the fixed class to the element using this jquery

```
$('.myElement').addClass('fixed');
```